# How to send my project to someone not nearby?

Tags: android, android-studio

Sorry for the title , maybe it's a little bit misleading , however I want to send my project as an App file to my mate so he can test it on his mobile

Is there anyway to do that ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give them your apk file for testing. To get the debug version of your APK file, go to

```
AndroidStudioProjects\ProjectName\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
```

Copy app-debug.apk and send it to your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting up your project on one of many test services.

https://fabric.io/downloads

Answer (score 0):

Run your source code once so as this dialog appears.[image]

Then go to your project folder and to the following path:
<path_to_project>/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

Send the app-debug.apk over mail or any other file transfer services to your mate